# Prove this geometric series derivation

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $n$ is non negative integer and $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ \ $\{0,1\}$

Then show that, below geometric series always hold for RHS

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(x-1)^i\binom{n+1}{i+1}$$

I just discovered this derivation but not able to prove it fully.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n+1 \choose i+1} (x-1)^i =\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  ~(x-1)^{k-1}{n+1 \choose k}= \frac{(1+x-1)^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ $$ \Rightarrow S= \sum_{i=0}^{n} x^{i}.$$

In the above we have used $i+1=k$

Comment: How $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}  ~(x-1)^{k-1}{n+1 \choose k}= \frac{(1+x-1)^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ ?

Comment: @Pruthviraj Since $\sum_{k=1}^{N} {N \choose k}y^k=(1+y)^N-1$